# Trx file full path test

Tags: c#, trx

I used Mstest.exe tool to execute tests, and it created automticlly trx file which contains all details about the tests results.

I want to get accsess from my .Net application to full path of every test from trx file but I can't find such field in the trx file, just guid number.

For example : the Trx file generate this : 136460b1-a82c-5643-db6e-e53df99gbf9f

While I expect to get this full path of the test : PaSqlTest1ce.SetItemHandlingCharacteristics.SqlTest1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the trx file
with look for  "Testdefinitions" tag, and 'storage', 'clasname', 'name', to make you full path